# How to add an animated splash screen?

Tags: iphone, ios, animation

I've seen loads of apps like **Sky News**, **Glympse** etc. have some kind of animation as the **splash screen** on their app.

I'm not sure if this is done as an animation in a **view controller** or **appdelegate** or if it is an **actual movie file**.

Does anybody have an idea of how this type of effect can be achieved?

Thanks.

Comment: what kind of animation you are looking for?

Comment: This question has been asked so many times before, did you try anything yourself?

Answer (score 0):

Yes an animating splash screen is a view controller. This [tutorial](http://spvarma.blogspot.ca/2011/06/splash-screen-with-animation-for-iphone.html) can help you create one.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create an animated loading screen, you can do like this:

.h

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
IBOutlet UIImageView *AnitmationimageView;
IBOutlet UIImageView *Loadimageview;
}

-(void)delay1;
-(void)delay2;
-(void)delay3;
```

.m

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
AnitmationimageView.animationImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
[UIImage imageNamed:@"L1.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"L2.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"L3.png"],
[UIImage imageNamed:@"L4.png"], nil];
[AnitmationimageView setAnimationRepeatCount:1];
AnitmationimageView.animationDuration = 3;
[AnitmationimageView startAnimating];
[self performSelector:@selector(delay1) withObject:nil afterDelay:3];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(void)delay1 {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[AnitmationimageView setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self performSelector:@selector(delay2) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];

}

-(void)delay2 {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[Loadimageview setAlpha:1];
[UIView commitAnimations];
[self performSelector:@selector(delay3) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5];
}

-(void)delay3 {
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[Loadimageview setAlpha:0];
[UIView commitAnimations];
}
```

All this code is taken from http://GeekyLemon.com

Comment: You should really be using animation blocks...

Comment: I use similar code in my app. Undies app (undies.my)

Answer (score 0):

just simply you can do this by adding screen full imageView & assigning array of images to the imageView's animationImages properties like this

```
for(int i = 1; i < numOfImages; i++) {
                [totalAnimationImages addObject:[UIImage imageNamed:
                                                 [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%d.png", image, i]]];
            }
           imageView.animationImages = totalAnimationImages;
            imageView.animationDuration = 1; //speed
            imageView.animationRepeatCount = 1; //infinite loop
            [imageView startAnimating];
```